# Mono for Android fails to re-install an app assemble

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I successfully install the app the first time but then deleted and tried to re-install (test and debug) an app to my nexus s 4.0 android phone. I now get a deployment error. IT fails during the Installing assemblies...:

Warning message 1:

> There is a shared runtime on the device whose version cannot be
>   determined. A new runtime will not be deployed. If the runtime needs
>   to be replaced, please manually remove it from the device.

Warning message 2:

> There is a platform support runtime on the device whose version cannot
>   be determined. A new platform support runtime will not be deployed. If
>   the platform support runtime needs to be replaced, please manually
>   remove it from the device.

Error message 1:

```
An error occurred installing the package assemblies.

Error datails: Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: No such file or directory--->

Output Window box: _GenerateJavaStubs: ResolvedAssemblies: C:\Users\King\Mono Andriod\My Territory\My Territory\bin\Debug\MyTerritory.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3\Mono.Android.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Mono.Security.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Data.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Mono.Data.Tds.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Transactions.dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll ResolvedUserAssemblies: C:\Users\King\Mono Andriod\My Territory\My Territory\bin\Debug\MyTerritory.dll _AddStaticResources: Resource obj\Debug\android\assets\machine.config is unchanged. Skipping. Resource obj\Debug\android\src\mono\MonoRuntimeProvider.java is unchanged. Skipping. Resource obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\Seppuku.java is unchanged. Skipping. _GeneratePackageManagerJava: Skipping target "_GeneratePackageManagerJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. _CreateBaseApk: Skipping target "_CreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. _CompileJava: Skipping target "_CompileJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. _CompileDex: Skipping target "_CompileDex" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. _BuildApkFastDev: Skipping target "_BuildApkFastDev" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. _Mandroid: Skipping target "_Mandroid" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. _Sign: Skipping target "_Sign" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. Done Building Project "C:\Users\King\Mono Andriod\My Territory\My Territory\MyTerritory.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target(s)).

Build succeeded. 0 Warning(s) 0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.69

Waiting for device.. Removing old runtime: Mono.Android.DebugRuntime [2147483647].. Removing old runtime: Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_10 [2147483647].. Removing any previous version.. Copying application to device... Getting installation path... Installing assemblies... ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I was able to get an app to deploy by:

- Going to the project properties
- Changing "Linking" to "Sdk and User Assemblies"
- Unchecking "Use Shared Runtime"
- Unchecking "Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)"

I'm uncertain why it's not working. I have Galaxy Nexus running Jelly Bean (Android 4.1).